# How to bind 'OnFocus' and 'OnBlur' to RadListBoxItems (or preferably the entire collection in one go)

Tags: javascript, jquery, telerik, focus

I have the following scenario:

- Button on page. Its text changes between two states. "Add Tab" and "Rename Tab" are the two states.
- RadListBox on page. It contains 1+ dynamically created RadListBoxItems.

The button initially says "Add Tab." When the user clicks on a tab, I change the button to say "Rename Tab." When the user clicks off of tabs, I would like to change the button back to "Add Tab."

I can use RadListBox's OnClientSelectedIndexChanged event to detect when the user has clicked on a tab. This event fires whenever a tab is selected. There is no event for having tabs become unselected, though.

As such, I thought it would be best to just use OnBlur and OnFocus. I did a bit of googling, and found this thread on the Telerik forums: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/listbox/radlistboxitem-onblur-amp-onfocus.aspx

This is close, but not quite, what I want. The code on that page says to do this:

```
$telerik.$(radListBox._getGroupElement()).focus(function () { });
```

With the above code -- if the user clicks an area of the RadListBox which is visible, but not populated with a RadListBoxItem, the focus event fires. However, if I click a RadListBoxItem inside of the RadListBox, the event does not fire. So basically, the focus event doesn't apply to RadListBoxItem children. I wouldn't expect it to, though, so that's acceptable.

I can't for the life of me figure out how to bind to all of the RadListBoxItem's children. I've tried various combinations of ".get_element()", but nothing seems to stick. At this point I am trying to figure out how the "OnClientSelectedIndexChanged" event detects the change... and then hopefully mimic that, but I'm not making any progress.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

```
<telerik:RadWindow ID="DashboardGlobalSettingsWindow" Runat="Server" IconUrl="~/Content/Dashboard/Icons/radwindow_settings.png" Title="Global Settings" Height="322px" Width="450px">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div ID="GlobalSettingsDecorationZone">


            <fieldset id="TabProperties">
                <legend>Tab Settings</legend>
                    <div id="TabPropertiesArea">
                        <div id="TabLeftSide">
                            <telerik:RadListBox ID="RadListBox1" Runat="server" AllowDelete="True" AllowReorder="True" EnableDragAndDrop="True" Skin="Web20" Height="95px" OnClientSelectedIndexChanged="OnClientSelectedIndexChanged" Width="150px" OnClientLoad="OnClientLoad" TabIndex="1" />
                        </div>
                        <div id="TabRightSide">
                            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="RadTextBox1" Runat="server" EmptyMessage="Enter tab name" Skin="Web20" Width="150px" />
                            <div id="TabButton">
                                <telerik:RadButton ID="RadButton2" Runat="server" Skin="Web20" Text="Add Tab" OnClientClicked="OnButtonClicked">
                                </telerik:RadButton>
                            </div>
                        </div>   
                    </div>
            </fieldset>

        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</telerik:RadWindow>

<telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" Runat="server">
<AjaxSettings>
    <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadListBox1">
        <UpdatedControls>
            <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadListBox1" />
        </UpdatedControls>
    </telerik:AjaxSetting>
    <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadButton2">
        <UpdatedControls>
            <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadListBox1" />
            <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadTextBox1" />
        </UpdatedControls>
    </telerik:AjaxSetting>
    <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadButton3">
        <UpdatedControls>
            <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadButton3" />
        </UpdatedControls>
    </telerik:AjaxSetting>
</AjaxSettings>
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>
```

Neither of the client-side events are relevant. SelectedIndexChange I'm just changing some CSS for non-related controls. OnClientLoad fires once at the start and is just for setting the CSS initially that SelectedIndexChange modifies.

The button's JS:

```
//Handles whether the button click was renaming or adding and swaps its state after.
function OnButtonClicked(button) {
    if (radTextBox1.get_value() != "") {
        if (button.get_text() == "Rename Tab") {
            var newName = radTextBox1.get_value();

            if (newName) {
                var selectedItem = radListBox1.get_selectedItem();
                radListBox1.trackChanges();
                selectedItem.set_text(newName);
                radListBox1.clearSelection();
                radListBox1.commitChanges();
                radTextBox1.clear();
                button.set_text("Add Tab");
            }
        }
        else if (button.get_text() == "Add Tab") {
            var item = new Telerik.Web.UI.RadListBoxItem();
            item.set_text($find(radTextBox1ID).get_value());
            item.set_value("RadTab_" + GenerateUniqueID());
            $find(radListBox1ID).trackChanges();
            $find(radListBox1ID).get_items().add(item);
            $find(radListBox1ID).commitChanges();
            $find(radTextBox1ID).clear();
        }

        radListBox1.clearSelection();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant HTML markup of your page?

Comment: I went and added the relevant HTML markup and JS.